# What happened to "Project onto self"(under snap)

Tags: sculpting, snapping

I am following a tutorial from before 3.0. At some point it comes to snapping options, and
**Project onto self** is missing. Or is it hidden somewhere? Help[image]

Comment: Project onto Self only available in editing mode. Screenshot shows object mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just had this issue and found out it was because I wasn't in edit mode.